# How to delete an element start with underscore ruby array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am having an array

```
["You purchased 2 tickets to: \n",
"____________________________________________________________________________\n",
"_________________ \n",
"The Temper Trap\n", "Webster Hall, New York, NY\n", "Fri, Apr 2, 2010 07:00 PM \n",
"\n", "Order for: Vikas Sekhri\n"]
```

I want to remove the underscore (means second and third element of an array). I need like this

```
["You purchased 2 tickets to: \n", "The Temper Trap\n", "Webster Hall, New York, NY\n", "Fri, Apr 2, 2010 07:00 PM \n", "\n", "Order for: Vikas Sekhri\n"]
```

Anyone can help me

Comment: Did you put any effort into the question before asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = ["You purchased 2 tickets to: \n", "____________________________________________________________________________\n", "_________________ \n", "The Temper Trap\n", "Webster Hall, New York, NY\n", "Fri, Apr 2, 2010 07:00 PM \n", "\n", "Order for: Vikas Sekhri\n"]

arr.reject { |elt| elt.starts_with? "_" }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.reject! {|element| element =~ /_/ }
```

This modifies the array. If you don't want it modified, use `reject` (without the bang) instead.